# Centering a inline-block wrapper div?

Tags: css, html

I am trying to achieve something like this: http://i.minus.com/ibxOaBw7BW8b5g.png

This is what I have so far: http://jsfiddle.net/QAPub/2/

How can I center the wrapper/container? I really don't care if the container exists or not, my main goal is the center the three black divs but this is as far as I have gotten.

HTML:

```
    <div class="clearfix">
        <div class="content"></div>
        <div class="content"></div>
        <div class="content"></div>
    </div>​
```

CSS:

```
    .clearfix:after { 
        content: " ";
        display: block; 
        height: 0; 
        clear: both;
     }
     .clearfix {
        background-color: orange;
         display: inline-block;
     }

     .content {
         float: left;
         background-color: black;
         border: 1px solid black;
         width: 100px;
         height: 100px;
         margin: 10px;
     }
```

​

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of different ways you can accomplish this.

Here's the one I would use, put the container in the body and give it margin and position it wherever you want to.

http://jsfiddle.net/QAPub/3/

```
body{
width:500px;
height:500px;
}

.clearfix {
position:relative;
background-color: orange;
display: block;
width:370px;
height:120px;
margin:auto;
top:20px;
}
.content {
float: left;
background-color: black;
border: 1px solid black;
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
margin: 10px;
}
```

​

Answer (score 0):

use the following css for ".clearfix "

```
.clearfix {
    background-color: orange;
    display:table;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

here is the [jsFiddle file](http://jsfiddle.net/AH9Mh/).